# NextJS doesn't create index.html for subfolders in static export

Tags: amazon-s3, next.js

I made a fully static website using NextJS, `export`ed it and I'm hosting it on S3 using static website hosting. I can click around and successfully view all the pages, including `example.com/blog`. However if in the browser I click refresh, or enter `example.com/blog` directly, I get a 404 Not Found error.

When viewing the exported files, I see that /blog/ has no index.html file, even though there should be (in my opinion) since in the original source files I have a `/blog/index.ts` file, and when in dev mode I can refresh `localhost/blog` or enter it directly and it works as expected.

In summary, I believe NextJS should create a `/blog/index.html` file but it doesn't. Is there any way to force this? Am I doing something wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To generate an `index.html` file when exporting to static HTML, enable the [`trailingSlash`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/trailing-slash) setting in your `next.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  trailingSlash: true,
}
```

`./out/blog.html` should now become `./out/blog/index.html` after the export.

Comment: It's now loading the blog page, but the styles are being loaded from `example.com/blog/_next/`, which is wrong so they aren't loaded at all.

Comment: @Sandy That issue is separate from your original question, so you might want to post a new one.

Comment: Updated my comment, not sure if yours still applies but I believe this new issue is part of the same thing.

Comment: @Sandy Is `blog` a page (i.e., `./pages/blog`) or a `basePath` in your `next.config.js`? Are you using absolute or relative paths when importing CSS? Also, does a clean build (deleting the `.next` directory before re-running `next build` and `next export`) fix anything?

Comment: Fixed! I believe the cause is that additionally I was using the `assetPrefix` config. Removing that and keeping `trailingSlash` fixed this. Thanks again.

Comment: `trailingSlash: true` helped on my side to create subfolders in static export, however now I've ended up with trailing slashes which given the parameter name is not a surprise. Is there anyway to configure static sub-folder build output without actually using trailing slashes?